# Changing Bootstrap form input font

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 17px;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
   font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 17px; 
}
```

Basically, the font on the "example@domain.com" gets the changes. But once I write into the field, the font is not the same and really has a weak look.
Keep in mind: I'm  fairly new to coding, I'm not surprised if I have errors in my codes or just bad structure on my codes.

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NBoX.png)

[How it looks like after writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdcrK.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only styling the `placeholder` at the moment. When you input something in an input field, the placeholder is automatically replaced with your data which means you will also have to style the content of `.input` and not just the `placeholder` for a proper result.

For example, use the following code:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 17px;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 17px; 
}

input {
  // Styling can be put here
}
```